# CSS image in the middle even if I scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this page here: http://paoladi.com/designers/

and I added this code:

```
<style type="text/css">

    .entry-content img { display: none; float:right; position: fixed; top: 36%; left: 30%; }
    .entry-content p{ width:30%; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:0px;}

    </style>
```

to always have the image in the middle of the page even if I scroll, I however have a small screen and looks fine on mine, I am just wondering how this looks on bigger screens and can I do to improve this code? Is jQuery an option?

To see an image, hover over '360 Sweaters'

Thanks,
J

Comment: To see an image, hover over '360 Sweaters'

Comment: can you post to a fiddle so future users can relate. if your site goes away they miss the lesson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the image size, you can use `calc()` in css to calculate the position dynamically.

In your case, if the image width is 200px and height is 100px;

```
<style type="text/css">

.entry-content img { display: none; float:right; position: fixed; top: calc(50% - 50px); left: calc(50% - 100px); }
.entry-content p{ width:30%; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:0px;}

</style>
```

Please see some detail in [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

In addition, you can also use javascript or jQuery to update the position if needed. For example, add an `.resize()` event to `$(window)`

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    $(".entry-content img").position({
        left: $('body').width() / 2 - $(".entry-content img").width() / 2,
        right: $('body').height() / 2 - $(".entry-content img").height() / 2,
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my screen, it isn't in the middle.

If you want to center it, since it has `position: fixed`, you can use [Absolute Centering](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) (or fixed, in this case):

```
.entry-content img {
    /* Fixed centering: */
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;

    /* The following makes sure that the image will be
       fully visible in small screens, but stretched: */
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I added your fix, but when I hover over '360 Sweaters' the image is up too way over the nav, on my screen atleast